# Only one component can be present per DOM element

Tags: angular, components

I have some confusion regarding angular component in angular official document says "**Only one component can be present per DOM element**" but I am able to use multiple times someone please explain.

Comment: Share an example of your multiple use

Answer (score 0):

In angular life cycle hook every component is destroyed when new component load.

> Angular is a managed component lifecycle by itself. Angular is able to create and render the component. It also renders the component children and also updates the data, when the associated model is changed and Angular destroys the component before removing from the DOM.